# Missing dylibs from Framework location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

After successfully building and archiving app, I'm trying to upload it to iTunes Connect, using Xcode Organizer.
The application successfully passes the validation and it uploading to iTunes Connect.
But then iTunes Connect sends me mail:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "[APP_NAME]". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app’s
>   Framework location, such as /Payload/[APP_NAME].app/Frameworks.

All the Frameworks and Libraries are linked to project.
Since app works on React Native and uses some Swift Libraries, I setted these values:

For main project: `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = Yes`

For custom framework: `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = No`

What I'm doing wrong? If app building and working on simulator.

P.S.: Also, i use these libraries: Google Signin and FacebookSDK, and they are both linked.

Comment: Same problem here.  I've been fighting this for days.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved, btw?